# Obtain an object with lists in it in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have an array `[2, 2, 4, 3]` and I am trying to obtain a dictionary thats something like `{2:[0,1], 3:3, 4:2}` that is basically a dictionary which contains the `items` in the array as `key` and its `indices` as the `value`, if there are multiple indices with the same item, then store the value in the dictionary as an array else as a normal value.

```js
var arr = [2,2,4,3];
var dict={};
var len=arr.length;
for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
   dict[arr[i]] = i;
}

console.log(dict);
```

The above snippet only take the latest instance of the item in the array as key and stores it as value, is there a way to make the value of the dictionary as an array if there are duplicate multiple items in the array. Also, I am a beginner in javascript so please ignore if its a stupid question.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary, that numbers, which occur only once, get unpacked, instead of e.g. "3: [3]"? Sure, it's possible, but why?

Comment: Expanding on what ASDFGerte said, it just makes things harder and can cause many functions to error when trying to process it. It's much easier if you keep as a 1 element array to stay consistent.

Comment: FYI, dictionaries are called objects in Javascript.

Comment: @ ASDFGerte As I have to search the dictionary later and find the indices which matches the result of an operation performed later. @Barmar thanks for that info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr = [2,2,4,3];
var dict={};
var len=arr.length;
for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
   if(dict[arr[i]] !== undefined)
   {
     if(Array.isArray(dict[arr[i]]))
     {
       dict[arr[i]].push(i);
     }
     else
     {
       dict[arr[i]] = [dict[arr[i]]];
       dict[arr[i]].push(i);
     }
   }
   else
     dict[arr[i]] = i;
}

console.log(dict);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer this is what I was looking for

Comment: I know its dumb, but can you please explain why you did `dict[arr[i]] = [dict[arr[i]]];`? coz even if I do `dict[arr[i]] = [];`, and then do `dict[arr[i]].push(i);` that creates an an array and inserts index `1`, but not the index `0`, can you please explain why?

Comment: That first line is creating a new array with the existing value as the first value in the array. When that line is called, `dict[arr[i]] == 0`, so `[dict[arr[i]]] == [0]`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is using the function `reduce` to group values with indexes.

```js
let arr = [2, 2, 4, 3],
    result = arr.reduce((a, c, i) => {
      let current = a[c];
      if (current || current === 0) {
        if (Array.isArray(current)) current.push(i);
        else a[c] = [current, i];
      } else a[c] = i;
      
      return a
    }, {});
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done very simply

```
const dict = array.reduce((result, value, index) => {
  if (!result[value]) {
    result[value] = [index];
  } else {
    result[value].push(index);
  }
  return result;
}, {});
```

Or, immutably:

```
const dict = array.reduce((result, value, index) => ({
  ...result,
  [value]: [...(result[value] || []), index]
}), {});
```